# How to swaggerize using openapi by reuse of existing scala case class

Tags: swagger, openapi, quarkus

I am using openapi to create swagger ui.

I want to be able to use the existing scala case classes to generate the required swagger ui elements instead of creating new java pojos.

e.g The StatusMessage scala case class

```
case class StatusMessage(
  @Schema(description = "Status being reported.", enumeration = Array("error", "warning", "success"), required = true)
  status: String = "error",
  @Schema(description = "List of messages regarding the status")
  messages: Seq[String] = Seq.empty[String]
)

The generated openapi document is below: 
    StatusMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
        messages:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/SeqString'
```

I do not see, description, enumeration and required attributes set in the @Schema annotation.

I have following API call,

```
@GET
  @Operation(summary = "Fetches all user profiles", description = "Fetches all user profiles desc")
  @Parameter(name = "locale", description = "the locale to request the definition (Optional).", required = false, in = ParameterIn.QUERY, example = "us_EN")
  @APIResponses({
      @APIResponse(
          responseCode = "200",
          description = "Success",
          content = {  @Content(
              schema = @Schema(type = SchemaType.ARRAY, implementation = UserProfileWrapper.class), mediaType = "application/json") }
              ),
      @APIResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Error", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = StatusMessage.class)) }), })
  public List<UserProfileWrapper> getDefinitions(
      RequestContext requestContext,
      HttpServerRequest request,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      @QueryParam("locale") String locale) {

        // implementation
      }
```

Comment: "I do not see, description, enumeration and required attributes set in the @Schema annotation." where you do not see them in the IDE intellij ? and can you share a reproducer ?